# Passing state between macros

Tags: macros, clojure

What is the best way to create a set of macros that share information with each other at compile time in Clojure?

I'm looking for some way of having macros know what previous macros have done and act accordingly, e.g. how would you implement macros that can be used like the following:

```
(macro-block-with-data ["A" "B" "C"]
   (process-next-data-item)    ; macro expands using "A"
   (process-next-data-item)    ; macro expands using "B"
   (process-next-data-item))   ; macro expands using "C"
```

**Clarifications**

- This needs to happen at compile time with macros, i.e. not with regular functions at runtime

Comment: I probably don't understand the question well enough.  As I read it, it seems like you want to `(map process-next-data-item ["A" "B" "C"])`.  So if not, maybe you could clarify this a little bit.

Comment: @kwbeam - doesn't fit the bill because a) it needs to be at compile time and b) in general the code won't be a simple map operation because there might be lots of other code in between each process-next-data-item call and c) The data might be anything (e.g. a counter of times the macro is expanded) rather than just a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it lexically scoped?  If so, you can do something like the following, which uses stateful iterators (kind of ugly, though).

```
(defmacro process-next-data-item []
  `(println "step" (.next ~'__state)))

(defmacro macro-block-with-data [dat & body]
  `(do
     (let [~'__state (.iterator ~dat)]
       ~@body)))
```

As an example:

```
(defn test []
  (macro-block-with-data ["A" "B" "C"]
    (println "start")
    (process-next-data-item)    ; macro expands using "A"
    (println "middle")
    (process-next-data-item)    ; macro expands using "B"
    (println "almost done")
    (macro-block-with-data [ "NestedA" "NestedB" ]
      (println "starting nested")
      (process-next-data-item)
      (process-next-data-item)
      (println "done nested"))
    (process-next-data-item)
    (println "done")))
```

... results in ...

```
user> (test)
start
step A
middle
step B
almost done
starting nested
step NestedA
step NestedB
done nested
step C
done
nil
```